# JAX-RS without container

Tags: java, web-services, interop, jnlp, browser-extension

This may sound like a strange request but is it possible to have a RESTeasy - jax-rs application without a container?

The reason I'm asking this is because I need a browser extension and some java code to communicate efficiently.

I have thought about sockets but that would leave me with the job of implementing all the communication details.

I have tried liveconnect but that does not work outside of the embedded applet world.

So I'm left with webservices.

The thing now is that the browser extension is launching a jnlp that should start the java application I really would prefer not to have the main() instantiate a jetty browser...

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have thought of arquillian but not really sure it would be a good solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who wish to have information about embedded container with RestEasy library, check that : http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html_single/#RESTEasy_Embedded_Container